# Restart iterator when finished

Tags: java, list

I have a list and I'd like to get the values at `i-1`, `i` and `i+1` positions. When `i` is the first or the last index, it would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. To prevent that, I would write a few `if-statements` and hardcode it like that:

```
if (i == 0){
    a = list.get(list.size()-1);
    b = list.get(0);
    c = list.get(1);
} else if (i == list.size()-1){
    a = list.get(i-1);
    b = list.get(i);
    c = list.get(0);
} else {
    a = list.get(i-1);
    b = list.get(i);
    c = list.get(i+1);
}
```

I find this way is a littlebit static. Let's say I want to get `n` entries from the list in this way, how would you do that?

Comment: This code looks very readable and understandable to me. It doesn't handle the case where the list contains a single element, though. What do you mean by getting N entries?

Comment: And if the list contains only 2 elements, you'll get the first or the second element twice, depending if `i=1` or `i=0`, respectively.

Comment: yes, I know the code is really bad, with N entries I want to say to get as much entries from the list as I want, once maybe this three, once from i-3 till i+3

Comment: This isn't really a coding question, right?  It's about you expressing what you want.  In short, if
`N = 2 * j + 1` and `k = list.size()`, then I think you want everything from element `(( i - j + k ) % k)` to element `(( i + j ) % k)`.  Write your own code iterating between those two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(i-1+list.size()) % list.size()` and `(i+1) % list.size()`.
This will also handle lists of length 1.

Heavier options:

- Write a method

  ```
  <T> T get(List<T> list, int i)
  {
      i %= list.size();
      return list.get(i >= 0 ? i : i + list.size());
  }
  ```
- Subclass and override `get()`
- Make a wrapper class which wraps around indices

Comment: OK, I've removed my downvote.  But really, have you answered the question?  The question is "how would you get `n` entries from the  list".  I don't see an answer here.

Comment: greate idea for (i+n)%list.size()

Comment: @DavidWallace The idea is to replace -1 and +1 with -n and +n. It appears the OP understood.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the ternary operator to shorten the code a little, and factor out the get calls to shorten the code further.

```
int prev, i, next;

//start loop here

prev = (i == 0 ? list.size()-1 : i-1);
next = (i == list.size()-1 ? 0 : i+1);

a = list.get(prev);
b = list.get(i);
c = list.get(next);

// end loop here
```

You will have to handle small lists, (size() <= 2) to stop repeating elements.

Comment: ternary operator: very useful, I always forget it

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't just iterate with foreach and reassign old values like this:

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 7, 3, 4);
 int n = 3;  // how much entries we take
 int a = 0, b = 0, c;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     c = b;
     b = a;
     a = list.get(i);
     // do some stuff
 }
```

Comment: could work, but then you have to stop once to get the three entries you want.

Comment: if you want to have the first, second and the last one, it gives you 0 1 5 instead of 4 1 5, and the same if you want to have the last one as "base".
But I'm wondering how you could use this iteration for something else, I think it could once be useful!